# prepositional phrases combined with "and" or "or" - style & punctuation

Tags: punctuation, prepositional-phrases

"Project X17 must not be confused with, and is totally independent of, project X107." - Is this stylistically acceptable? And what is the correct punctuation: is the second comma obligatory, optional, or wrong?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. (I'm almost certain this is a duplicate, but it's not at all easy tracking down the precursor.) // The sentence is grammatically fine, idiomatic in a formal register (though I'd probably use 'Project X17 is totally independent of, and must not be confused with, project X107' , and the comma is necessary to aid parsing and maintain symmetry.